# In Rust, I want to read from a stream or file to fill a buffer, and detect EOF

Tags: rust, io

In Rust, I want to read (using BufReader) into a buffer array to fill it. I want to read the exact number of bytes, except in case of EOF, where reading less is fine. I have implemented a helper method myself, as follows, and that works. However I wonder if there is no convenience method that already does exactly that.

```
pub fn read_fully<R: Read>(read: &mut R, buffer: &mut [u8]) -> Result<usize, Error> {
    let mut count: usize = 0;
    loop {
        let r = read.read(&mut buffer[count..])?;
        if r == 0 {
            return Ok(count);
        }
        count += r;
    }
}
```

With each existing method I found there seems to be a problem:

- "read" may read less (e.g. for stdin).
- "read_exact" doesn't work well with EOF.
- "read_to_end" expects a Vec and not an array, and will read everything, possibly expanding the vector.

Comment: `read_to_end()` is not what you want. It will read more bytes than wanted until the end of the file. I don't think there is another method you can use, your custom code is fine.

Comment: One thing you may want to do is to ignore `ErrorKind::Interrupted` and just repeat the read in this case.

Comment: Yes I tried read_to_end() and found it can read more bytes... I changed the question. Thanks about the tip for ErrorKind::Interrupted: when reading about it, it seems the loop should ignore this and continue. This makes it more complicated, but it seems to make sense.

Comment: Quick note. You should take `R: Read` directly instead of `&mut R` per [API guidelines](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/interoperability.html#generic-readerwriter-functions-take-r-read-and-w-write-by-value-c-rw-value)

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze I'm not sure what you mean exactly. Do you mean replace `&mut R` with `R`? That doesn't compile ("Cannot borrow immutable local variable `read` as mutable" for read.read).

Comment: @ThomasMueller Mark it as `mut` (`mut read: R`).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman thanks a lot! That works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it shorter and cleaner, but using an experimental API:

```rust
#![feature(read_buf, core_io_borrowed_buf)]

use std::io::{BorrowedBuf, Error, ErrorKind, Read};

pub fn read_fully<R: Read>(read: &mut R, buffer: &mut [u8]) -> Result<usize, Error> {
    let mut buffer = BorrowedBuf::from(buffer);
    match read.read_buf_exact(buffer.unfilled()) {
        Ok(()) => {}
        Err(err) if err.kind() == ErrorKind::UnexpectedEof => {}
        Err(err) => return Err(err),
    }
    Ok(buffer.len())
}
```

At this point, you may want to just have a `BorrowedCursor` as a parameter:

```rust
#![feature(read_buf, core_io_borrowed_buf)]

use std::io::{BorrowedCursor, Error, ErrorKind, Read};

pub fn read_fully<R: Read>(read: &mut R, buffer: BorrowedCursor<'_>) -> Result<(), Error> {
    match read.read_buf_exact(buffer) {
        Err(err) if err.kind() == ErrorKind::UnexpectedEof => Ok(()),
        v => v,
    }
}
```

This allows neat things like using an uninitialized buffer.

Comment: Thanks, interesting! I will use it once it is no longer experimental

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea, which I'm not sure is better than yours, but it also works:

```rust
pub fn read_fully<R: Read>(read: &mut R, buffer: &mut [u8]) -> Result<usize, Error> {
    let mut data = Vec::with_capacity(buffer.len());
    read.take(buffer.len().try_into().unwrap())
        .read_to_end(&mut data)?;
    buffer[..data.len()].copy_from_slice(&data);
    Ok(data.len())
}
```

It'll probably be much less efficient. Whether it's clearer is up to you to decide.

Comment: Yes I would prefer the method to be efficient (no memcpy). Verbose is fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that ErrorKind::Interrupted should be ignored. So the solution would become:

```
pub fn read_fully<R: Read>(mut read: R, buffer: &mut [u8]) -> Result<usize, Error> {
    let mut count: usize = 0;
    loop {
        let r = read.read(&mut buffer[count..]);
        match r {
            Ok(0) => {
                return Ok(count)
            },
            Ok(x) => {
                count += x
            },
            Err(e) => {
                if e.kind() == ErrorKind::Interrupted {
                    // retry
                } else {
                    return Err(e);
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```